# Class not recognizing method in other class

Tags: c#, methods

I'm a new C# programmer, and am wondering why I'm getting a `object does not contain a definition of '`methodName`' and no extension method '`methodName`' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found` error. I'm not sure why it seems the two classes aren't connected.

Here is the class with my method definitions:

```
namespace Simple_Restaurant_Simulation
{
    class ChickenOrder
    {
        public int quantity;
        public int GetQuantity(int ChickenQuantity)
        {
            this.quantity = ChickenQuantity;
            return quantity;
        }

        public void CutUp()
        {
            return;
        }

        public void Cook()
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and the calling methods:

```
namespace Simple_Restaurant_Simulation
{
    class Employees
    {
        public dynamic NewRequest(int Quantity, string MenuItem)
        {
            if (MenuItem == "Chicken")
            {
                return new ChickenOrder();
            }

            else
            {
                return new EggOrder();
            }
        }

        public dynamic CopyRequest(dynamic MenuItem)
        {
            /*TODO: 
            if(existing order){
                return existing order;
            }           

            else { return "Whaddaya think I am, a miracle worker?"};

            */
            return null;
        }

        public int Inspect(object Order)
        {
            int InspectResult = 0;

            return InspectResult;
        }

        private string PrepareFood(object Order)
        {

            string PrepareResult = null;

            try
            {
                if (Order is ChickenOrder)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i < this.GetQuantity; i++)
                    {
                        Order.CutUp();
                    }
                    Order.Cook();
                    PrepareResult =  "Chicken order has been cooked";
                }
                                return PrepareResult;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What line is your error?

Comment: Hint: what's the compile-time type of the `Order` variable? The use of the `is` operator doesn't change that...

Comment: Does ChickenOrder even inherit from Order?

Comment: New programmers should not use `dynamic` or `object`. Dynamic is mainly for specific interop scenarios. Get a real compile-time type in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here but the reason why the `PrepareMethod` doesn't compile is that it accepts an `object` and the `object` type obviously has no `CutUp()` method.

You could use the [as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator to try to cast the `Order` object to a `ChickenOrder`:

```
ChickenOrder chickenOrder = Order as ChickenOrder;
if (chickenOrder != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i< this.GetQuantity; i++)
    {
        chickenOrder.CutUp();
    }
    chickenOrder.Cook();
    PrepareResult =  "Chicken order has been cooked";
}
```

Note that the cast will only succeed if the object that you are passing the `PrepareFood` method at runtime actually is a `ChickenOrder`. And for you to be able to pass a `ChickenOrder` object to a method that accepts an `Order` argument, the `ChickenOrder` class should inherit from `Order`:

```
class ChickenOrder : Order
{
    ...
}
```

Both `EggOrder` and `ChickenOrder` are specific types of orders that should inherit from the `Order` base class. This also means that you can change the return type of the `NewRequest` method from `dynamic` to `Order` and the type of the parameter that you are passing to the other methods from `object` to `Order`.